# My functions' and its arguments' names in disassembly visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly

I deassembled some delphi, pure basic and even visual c++ non-packed programs and have seen only function addresses and Arg1, Arg2 as its arguments in OllyDbg. But when i disassemble my visual c++ program, i can see functions' and arguments' names. Is there any compilation flag or something else to remove procedure names from PE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can see functionname and arguments in your disassembly, it means that the debugging information is available. If you disassemble a file which is compiled in release mode, then the symbolic information is removed. In this case the disassembler doesn't know about names and can only provide adresses, and as arguments, what it can infer from the code.

When compiling, you can enable/disable the inclusion of debugging information. By default, this is removed in release mode.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, looks like Olly reads generated .pdb file in release folder, thats the problem. Im noob